# Reference error is not defined Angular 2 Typings

Tags: angular, webpack, typescript-typings

I am trying to include a 3rd party module in my application with webpack, like so

```
//package.json
 "dependencies": {
          "jsrsasign": "6.1.4"
 }

//custom-typings.d.ts
declare module KJUR {
module jws {
    module JWS {
        function readSafeJSONString(token: string): any;
        function verifyJWT(token: string, key: string, data: Object): boolean;
   }
  }
}

//webpack.json
entry: {
   'vendor':    './src/vendor.browser.ts',
},

//vendor.browser.ts
import 'jsrsasign';
```

I can see in Chrome that the module is being loaded into node_modules and I can open it up from the webpack folder in Chrome. Here is code in a component that calls the module

```
  let tokenHeader: TokenHeader = KJUR.jws.JWS.readSafeJSONString(token.split('.')[0]);
```

Yet when I get to this line, I get

> app.component.ts:45 ReferenceError: KJUR is not defined

I am guessing I am missing a step here, as I have followed all the tutorials I can fine. Do I need to import jsrsasign into my module as well? Component? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it to ProvidePlugin like so:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html

Comment: no that did not seem to work either, though I may have done it wrong. I added KJUR: 'jsrsasign' to it

Answer (score 0):

You need to import KJUR:

```ts
import { KJUR } from 'jsrsasign';

declare module KJUR {
    export module jws {
        export class JWS {
            static readSafeJSONString(token: string): any;
            static verifyJWT(token: string, key: string, data: Object): boolean;
        }
    }
}
```